# Looking for a clip showing how cool GIS is

Tags: education

Next year I will be teaching a GIS course since this is not a compulsory course I have to make the students register. I thought of producing an e-mail brochure with a few lines of text and a clip showing what is GIS and how cool it can be.

Does anyone have an idea to such clip?

Comment: Have you looked for "gis introduction" on youtube? There are a lot of examples. If you cannot find anything fitting, please describe what should be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows the OpenStreetMap mapping response in the two weeks after the Haiti crisis.
http://vimeo.com/9182869

Comment: Ok, for whoever reads it in the future i further investigated from this clip and got to this:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJvR84UX5RI, cliped some of it and this is what i use:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XK7R7KoQmc4&feature=plcp

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of the [Geospatial Revolution Project](http://geospatialrevolution.psu.edu/) fantastic videos.

Comment: I also used this great link

Answer (score 1):

You might decide to choose the OSGeo [LiveDVD](http://live.osgeo.org/en/index.html) as a platform for teaching. Using that DVD insures that all students get identical installations, and preinstalled data.
On the DVD there are "quickstarts" for all the the installed software, including one for QGIS, with a few brief examples. You could snatch this document from the Live system as a "teaser".

Micha

Comment: Although i am going to run this in qgis and although i am a linux user myself i decided to go osgeo4w. I will check those clips

Answer (score 0):

A recent example comes to mind: Google Mars Curiosity landing animation.

But is that *cool*? Perhaps a better one would be showing them the intro to Enemy of the State movie, where there is some creepy live and detailed satellite tracking going on.